# What are the rules of settling?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm pretty new to Civilization, but I'm getting the hang of the rules I think. Recently, I had a settler and was going to have him create a city in this narrow strip land, but was told I couldn't settle a city within 4 spaces of another city. I interpreted that as "not within 4 spaces of the boundary of ANY city (even other players)... but I think I got that wrong because Russia just settled a city right on my border... so can anyone explain what specifically is meant by this rule?

Also, is there anyway to stop Russia's settler without going to war with them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is from the actual city tile, not the border of the city. So, Russia can build adjacent to your border as long as that border does not fall within 4 tiles of one of your cities.

[image]
On the city state's border

[image]
Suddenly a wild city appears

Comment: upvoted for the second caption :D

Comment: is there anyway from stopping them from settling right on my border other than war? peace not war bro

Comment: You can ask them not to settle near you, but I have yet to see it make a huge difference.

Comment: @Josh To keep them from settling near you, lots of culture and don't accept open borders. Or just preemptively settle everywhere.

Comment: It also depends on how the AI civilizations expand, some civilizations don't build many cities and it is much safer to not be so militant on your borders.

Comment: aqcuire any useful resources by settling or border expand before they can settle there, i like using a wall of troops to stop them from getting through.

Comment: yeah i ended up putting a troop where she wanted to settle until she decided to go to war with a city-state, then i brought the hammer down